# lighttpd/mod_wstunnel concatenates JSON messages

Tags: websocket, lighttpd

I'm trying to use `lighttpd` (v1.4.49) with `mod_wstunnel`.

```
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/websocket" {
    wstunnel.server = ( "" => ( ( "host" => "127.0.0.1", "port" => "50007" ) ) )
    wstunnel.frame-type = "text"
    wstunnel.ping-interval = 30
}
```

The backend TCP-Server sends single line JSON-Messages that should be received by the WebSocket-Clients `onmessage` handler.

However, sometimes two successive messages are concatenated by `mod_wstunnel` and received (and passed to `onmessage`) as one message.

Is there any "end-of-message" token I could send to explicitly "tell" `mod_wstunnel` that the message is complete?

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 0):

You should probably fix your application if your application depends on framing at the websockets layer.  See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455#section-5.4

```
Unless specified otherwise by an extension, frames have no semantic
meaning. An intermediary might coalesce and/or split frames, if no
extensions were negotiated by the client and the server or if some
extensions were negotiated, but the intermediary understood all the
extensions negotiated and knows how to coalesce and/or split frames
in the presence of these extensions. One implication of this is that
in absence of extensions, senders and receivers must not depend on
the presence of specific frame boundaries.
```

Your backend is sending JSON and knows nothing about websockets, and therefore can not specify how mod_wstunnel should send websocket frames.  Your client app should not depend on the websocket framing, but if you wanted to try to mitigate this on the server-side, your backend could pause between sending each JSON message.  It would be better to fix your app to process complete JSON messages, one at a time.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately the application (i.e. Web-Application) is out of my control. I'm just the backend-guy.